# Windows 7 firewall commands

Tags: windows-7, firewall

Ok, call me lazy. This works in WINDOWS XP:

```
netsh firewall add portopening protocol=TCP port=5900 name="VNC"
```

What's the equivalent in Windows 7 ?

The documentation is as clear an  encrypted man page.
Thought I'll get some quick answers here ...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, have it your way. You're lazy. Have a -1 for asking a question that you put zero effort into solving yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I <3 Stackexchage, I just found the answer, leaving it for future reference:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”Rule” dir=in action=allow enable=yes remoteip=172.16.1.1 profile=private protocol=TCP localport=80
```

or for my case:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="vnc" dir=in action=allow enable=yes  profile=private protocol=TCP localport=5900
```